# Unity : Can we add an icon with EditorUtility.DisplayDialog?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wonder if ever with EditorUtility.DisplayDialog we can add or modify the icon displayed in the dialog box.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialogComplex.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialog.html

Comment: If it's not exposed, it cannot be done with these methods. If you could directly connect to the local OS library, that would not be an issue, but it's a wrapper around that.
If you really want to change it, you can write your own, but you'd probably write it for every separate platform, depending on where you want to use it.

Comment: Yeah i think too.